# How can i load class in notebook when tab is clicked in wxpython?

Tags: python-3.x, wxwidgets, wxpython

Here i have a doubt that when notebook tab is clicked at that time only it should load class in that tab. But in wxpython all class loads by default in tab so how can i put conditions to load class when tab is clicked.
Here is a small example.

```
import wx

class tabclass(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is the help tab", (20,20))

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="notebook")
        mainPanel = wx.Panel(self,size=(1365, 700), pos=(0, 71), style=wx.DOUBLE_BORDER)
        self.nb = wx.Notebook(mainPanel,size=(1365, 700))
        tab0 = tabclass(self.nb)
        self.nb.AddPage(tab0, "Tab One")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()  
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Here I want to display static text when the tab is clicked otherwise class should not load.

Comment: @mihrbhatt, why? that's not how things work. It doesn't take any resources to just load the tab layout. Because as soon as you call `AddPage()` the page is added to notebook and every control on the page is created. You can of course catch the page changing event, but what will you do when the user switches to a different page? You will just waste everything - processor time, execution time  and resoures

Comment: I appreciate that but when i want gui to load faster then how should i load class when tab is clicked?

Comment: @mihrbhatt, you will NOT gain any speed for loading it. In fact you program may slow down with te way you want it to behave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want a different method of selecting what is and what is not displayed in the notebook.
A menu, for example, seems an appropriate selection tool.
i.e.

```
import wx

class tabclass(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        t = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "This is the help tab", (20,20))

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="notebook")
        mainPanel = wx.Panel(self,size=(1365, 700), pos=(0, 71), style=wx.DOUBLE_BORDER)
        self.nb = wx.Notebook(mainPanel,size=(1365, 700))

        tabmenu = wx.Menu()
        t1 = wx.MenuItem(tabmenu, id = -1, text="Help", kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        tabmenu.Append(t1)
        t2 = wx.MenuItem(tabmenu, id = -1, text="Other tab", kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        tabmenu.Append(t2)
        t3 = wx.MenuItem(tabmenu, id = -1, text="Another tab", kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
        tabmenu.Append(t3)
        tabmenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, '&Quit')

        # Creating the menubar.
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        # Add menus
        menuBar.Append(tabmenu, "&Tabs")
        # Adding the MenuBar to the Frame content.
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        # Bind menu item to functions
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.helptab, t1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.othertab, t2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.anothertab, t3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, id=wx.ID_EXIT)

    # Obviously, here you would differentiate your tabs
    # I have used the same one for brevity
    def helptab(self, event):
        if event.IsChecked():
            self.tab0 = tabclass(self.nb)
            self.nb.AddPage(self.tab0, "Help Tab")
        else:
            #Delete the "Help Tab"
            pass

    def othertab(self, event):
        if event.IsChecked():
            self.tab1 = tabclass(self.nb)
            self.nb.AddPage(self.tab1, "Other Tab")
        else:
            #Delete the "Other Tab"
            pass

    def anothertab(self, event):
        if event.IsChecked():
            self.tab2 = tabclass(self.nb)
            self.nb.AddPage(self.tab2, "Another Tab")
        else:
            #Delete the "Another Tab"
            pass

    def OnQuit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    MainFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rolf of Saxony. I have one more doubt that i want to load thousands of images from folder in wx panel so what should be the best way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mihirbhatt The `wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl` widget springs to mind but that is an entirely different question.

Comment: of Saxoy Thanks for suggestions. I tried that when there around 5000 images scroll bar of thumbnail control is bit lagging. I used WrapSizer().

Comment: @mihirbhatt Colour me surprised! Five thousand seems excessive, can't you sub-divide the images into sub-directories. p.s. use the `imagehandler=thumbnailctrl.PILImageHandler` it's meant to be quicker.